# Divergent sequence which is always greater than its limsup?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(a_n)$ be a divergent sequence and $\alpha = \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n$. Is it possible for there to exist an $N$ such that $a_n > \alpha$ for all $n>N$?

(If we are interested in $a_n > \alpha$ infinitely often, then the sequence $(a_n)$ alternating between $(1+1/n)$ for $n$ odd and $-1$ for $n$ even should work, since $\alpha=1$.)

Comment: Do you mean *divergent* in the sense "not convergent", or "terms are unbounded"?

Comment: @Chappers ??? Why conjecture he may mean something other than "divergent"?

Comment: @Chappers I meant _divergent_ in the sense of "not convergent" (as in e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivergentSequence.html).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Because there are several conventions for what the word means?

Comment: @Chappers Really? That's news to me. Yes, of course there are several ways a sequence can be divergent, but that doesn't imply that the word means anything other than "not convergent". Do you have a reference where it means something else?

Comment: [Jeffreys and Jeffreys](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=odULAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA12&ots=0gX5gSXYxL&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q&f=false) notes there are differing definitions, for example (paragraph about halfway down the page, starting "These cannot be said [...]")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The first version of this answer was wrong. Actually there *does* exist a divergent sequence with the stated property.

**Hint:** What I said was this:

No. If $a_n>\alpha$ for all $n>N$ then $\liminf a_n\ge\alpha=\limsup a_n$: hence $\liminf a_n=\limsup a_n$ so $(a_n)$ is convergent.

That's not right - I'm assuming something that's not given. In fact $\limsup a_n=\liminf a_n$ does *not* imply $(a_n)$ is convergent, for example...

(Hint for that: $\limsup a_n=\liminf a_n$ *does* imply that $\lim a_n$ exists, but it does not imply that $(a_n)$ is convergent. What???)

Comment: It seems you are assuming $(a_n)$ is bounded? But how can $\lim a_n$ exist with  $(a_n)$ not convergent?

Comment: Yes, the unwarranted assumption is that $\;omsup a_n$ is finite. If $a_n=-n$ then $(a_n)$ is divergent and $a_n>\limsup a_n$. (And in that case $(a_n)$ is divergent although $\lim a_n$ exists...)

Comment: I guess I'm really confused now. If $a_n = -n$ how can you say that $(a_n)$ is divergent although $\lim a_n$ exists? I thought that (by definition) the limit is said to "exist" if and only if $a_n$ is convergent... Perhaps you are saying that $\lim a_n$ exists, and it is equal to $-\infty$ since $\limsup a_n = \liminf a_n = \lim a_n = -\infty$?

Comment: Yes, if $a_n=-n$ then $\lim a_n=-\infty$.